# is there a way of saving data with image for example productname, and productImage to cloudfirestore and retrieving them in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using cloudfirestore as my backend for my project, I need to save some information containing images, then after I want to retrieve the information and display it in my flutter app. I was successful with saving and retrieving information without image, so I need someone to help me how I can upload the information with the image. thanks for any help given.

Comment: Is there anything you have tried to upload the image?

Comment: i followed some tutorial about uploading images to firebase storage and it was successful

Comment: So the problem is when you try to upload data to Firestore?

Comment: yes, i dont know if it is possible to do it because i have searched for solutions but i haven't got, mostly i only get those ones uploading without images or only images. but me i want how i can combine all the description with image

Comment: Have you tried to write the image URL to Firestore, right after the upload completes?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.